# Ruby SketchUp LoadError if requiring correct files

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have the problem that I want to `require` a ruby file.

File overview:

```
ExcelConversion.rb
main.rb
/classes/excelReader.rb
/classes/elementIdentifier.rb
```

the `main.rb` has the header:

```
require classes/excelReader
require classes/elementIdentifier
```

the `excelReader.rb` has the header:

```
require 'rubyXL
```

the `elementIdentifier.rb` has the header:

```
require 'inifile
```

The problem is that if I execute the `main.rb` file, everything works fine. But, as soon as I write `require main` within the `ExcelConversion` file I get the error:

```
Error Loading File ExcelConversion.rb
Error: #<LoadError: cannot load such file -- rubyXL>
C:/Program Files (x86)/SketchUp/SketchUp 2018/Tools/RubyStdLib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
C:/Program Files (x86)/SketchUp/SketchUp 2018/Tools/RubyStdLib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
C:/shortenedPath/ExcelConversion/classes/ExcelReader.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
C:/shortenedPath/ExcelConversion/main.rb:1:in 'require_relative'
C:/shortenedPath/ExcelConversion/main.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
C:/shortenedPath/ExcelConversion.rb:4:in 'require_relative'
C:/shortenedPath/ExcelConversion.rb:4:in '<top (required)>'
```

I don't understand how that is even possible to throw an error, since the `main.rb` runs without problems.

---

Edit: Solution 
I managed to find the solution. SketchUp needs to install the gems separately. This can be achieved through the Ruby Console and the command:
`Gem.install "nameOfTheGem"` 
Then SketchUp stores a copy of the gem within it's own path and one can `require` it as usual.

Comment: Did you try requiring rubyxl at the beginning of your `ExcelConversion.rb` and seeing if that would help? Also, I see you have a require_relative in there which requires the file relative to the current path of the file, and can cause errors when run in a new context.

Comment: yes I did and sadfully that didn't help.:/

the structure is still right. Checked it like 4 times. `ExcelConversion.rb` and `main.rb` are in the same folder

Comment: Did you install through rubygems? There is some talk about files not being found without a require 'rubygems' statement.

Comment: Yes using it in the gemfile. Already tried to reinstall them thorugh console started as admin. I'm using Win10 by the way...

Comment: I tried to require them with an absolute path. That worked for `inifile.rb`, but not for `rubyXL.rb`. Maybe because the one is a single file and the other contains multiple others?

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade, upvoting one of your questions or answers for an edit? That's a new one on me, and I can't say I'm impressed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, good point to be made. But the spelling does make the question easier to be read. Less frustrating. You'd be surprised how many people downvote because of bad spelling and caps.